# Mvc: Custom default route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have my own default route like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{country}/{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

But when my website starts it´s searching for /Home route and it doesn´t exist, i need to pass that country and lang parameters when it starts but i don´t know where ? and get my default route with something like ES/es/Home.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an article which I believe answers your problem. It's relatively short and explains it very well!! It is truly about adding constraints to your routes.
Hope it helps! 

 http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for default values for country and lang, just change the default option,

```
defaults: new { country="ES", lang="es", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
```

It will fill country and lang option with the default value.

Or if your requirement is to set your applications starting url as,

```
www.site.com/ES/es
```

put the following code in Application_BeginRequest

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.Compare(Request.Path, Request.ApplicationPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            Response.Redirect(Request.Path + "ES/en");
}
```

**Edit**

The code in Application_BeginRequest will execute for each request including resource(js/css) url. You can remove the Application_BeginRequest code and put the code to the top in the default action of the default controller to have the same effect. like:

```
//Home Controller
public ActionResult Index(string country, string lang)
{
    if (String.Compare(Request.Path, Request.ApplicationPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
        return Redirect(Request.Path + string.Format("{0}/{1}", country, lang));
    return View();
}
```

**Edit**

the code,

```
if (String.Compare(Request.Path, Request.ApplicationPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
        return Redirect(Request.Path + string.Format("{0}/{1}", country, lang));
```

checks if the incoming url is the root url for the application and if so redirect with the additional route information. Ideally the `Request.Path` and `Request.ApplicationPath` both will have value `/` for starting url. Here this checking is done in the starting/default url only, so i don't think this code will cause the site to slow down noticeably. You might comment out the code, and check if the performance increases to make sure if this code is the cause for the performance.

Comment: i have a layout page where i import my javascript and css files and now this is comparing each javascript and css i have in my website, when i reload the page, how can i avoid that ? thanks.

Comment: @Steve Edited another possibility. Take a look.

Comment: it continues working perfect, thanks, but it is only one more thing, i can see the perfomance of the website is reduced a little, it takes more time loading the page, am i right ?, and why happen this ?, if you could explain to me i would really aprecciate it. Thank you again. ;)